# How to get updated CSS width of a Vue element in a flexbox grid after it has changed?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, flexbox, vuetify.js

This one is a head scratcher for me. Maybe I am not seeing something in the Vue lifecycle that I should be taking into account. I'll try to make this as simple as possible.

I have a custom button component that is being sized by a flex grid container. The grid looks something like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="component d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1" style="min-height: 0">
        <div class="justify-center align-content-center" 
        style="display: grid; width: 100%; height: 100%; grid-gap: 1rem;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
        grid-template-rows: repeat(8, minmax(0, 1fr));">
            <slot/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have a grid panel that looks like this:

```
<template> 
    <v-card :style="cardStyle" v-bind="$attrs">
        <slot></slot>
    </v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        cardStyle: function() {
            return 'grid-column: span ' + (this.columns || 2) +
            '; grid-row: span ' + (this.rows || 2) + ';';
        }
    },
    props: {
        columns: [Number, String],
        rows: [Number, String],
    }
}
</script>
```

And My Button uses the panel for sizing like this:

```
<template>
    <grid-panel ref="elm" :columns='columns || 2' :rows='rows || 2' elevation="0">
        <v-btn class="ma-0 align-stretch flex-column py-4" 
        width="100%" max-width="100%" height="100%" :color="color || 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'">

            <div class="d-flex fill-height py-2" style="width:100%;">
                <div ref="iconTest" class="fill-height">
                    <v-icon ref="icon" class="mb-0 flex-shrink-1 notransition py-0 pr-2" :color="iconColor" style="width:auto; height:auto">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
                </div>
                <div ref="text" class="flex-grow-1 d-flex align-center text-center">
                    <span ref="innerSpan" style="font-size: 1px" class="textFitted text-center d-inline-block notransition">
                        {{ label }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </v-btn>
    </grid-panel>
</template>
```

I know this looks like a mess, but just bear with me for a second.

I wanted a way to ensure that any text or label I put in this button would not get clipped. Not that I would ever have a massive amount of text as a label, but unlike traditional buttons on the web, these will be of a fixed size based on how they are placed in the grid; the grid would resize itself based on the screen it is displayed on. To solve this problem, I wanted to automatically size the text to fill the available space. So, using JS I came up with this:

```
// Calculate height without padding.
innerHeight(el){
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    return el.clientHeight -
    parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-top'), 10) -
    parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-bottom'), 10);
},

// Calculate width without padding.
innerWidth(el){
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    return el.clientWidth -
    parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-left'), 10) -
    parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('padding-right'), 10);
},

    updateFontSize() {

        if (!this.isMounted || this.$refs.text == undefined) 
            return;

        // Everything below here is taken from the textFit JS library
        // https://github.com/STRML/textFit/blob/master/textFit.js
        // By default - the library does not work well with Vue, and I had to modify it some

        let el = this.$refs.text;
        let innerSpan = this.$refs.innerSpan;

        innerSpan.style.fontSize = '1px';

        let originalWidth = this.innerWidth(el);
        let originalHeight = this.innerHeight(el);

        console.log(el);
        console.log(originalWidth);

        // Don't process if we can't find box dimensions
        if (!originalWidth || !originalHeight) {
            throw new Error('Set a static width on the target element ' + el.outerHTML +
                ' before using textFit!');
        }


        let low = 4;
        let high = 36;
        let mid;

        // Binary search for highest best fit
        let size = low;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (high + low) >> 1;
            innerSpan.style.fontSize = mid + 'px';
            if(innerSpan.scrollWidth <= originalWidth && innerSpan.clientHeight <= originalHeight){
                size = mid;
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        // found, updating font if differs:
        innerSpan.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

    },
```

It is relatively simple to understand, and it works very well. All this does is look at the available space in the div containing the text, which is set to fill the space thanks to flexbox, and the grows the text until it overflows.

Then I figured, well I might as well do the same for the icon right....?

Ok, so this is where my confusion begins.

*The Icon resizing itself works just fine.*  EDIT::
Actually, I think I might have been wrong... I was just playing around with this and I have discovered something interesting. See Edit below.

What I thought would need to happen is that I would size the icon first, which would allow the css to grow and shrink the 2 flex items, then size the text. Here is the code for sizing the icon, and you'll see a bunch of console.logs and commented out bits that are the remnants of me pulling my hair out.

```
let widthOnly = this.rows != 1;
let heightOnly = this.rows == 1;

let el = this.$refs.iconTest;
let innerSpan = this.$refs.icon.$el;

let el2 = this.$refs.text;

console.log('text elem before:');            
console.log(el2);
console.log(this.innerWidth(el2));

this.$refs.innerSpan.style.fontSize = '1px';
innerSpan.style.fontSize = '1px';

let originalWidth = this.innerWidth(el);
let originalHeight = this.innerHeight(el);

// Don't process if we can't find box dimensions
if (!originalWidth || !originalHeight) {
    throw new Error('Set a static width on the target element ' + el.outerHTML +
        ' before using textFit!');
}

console.log('text elem during 1:');            
console.log(el2);
console.log(this.innerWidth(el2));

innerSpan.style.fontSize = originalHeight + 'px';


let low = 4;
let high = 80;
let mid;

// Binary search for highest best fit
let size = low;
while (low <= high) {
    mid = (high + low) >> 1;
    innerSpan.style.fontSize = mid + 'px';
    if((heightOnly || innerSpan.clientWidth <= originalWidth) && (widthOnly || innerSpan.clientHeight <= originalHeight)){
        size = mid;
        low = mid + 1;
    } else {
        high = mid - 1;
    }
}
// found, updating font if differs:
innerSpan.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
// this.iconSize = size + 'px';


// THIS IS WHERE HELL HAPPENS

console.log('text elem after:');            
console.log(el2);
console.log(" BEFORE DELAY !!! ");
console.log(this.innerWidth(this.$refs.text)); // <-- This should be calculated after the icon has completely resized.

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(" AFTER DELAY !!!! ");
    console.log(this.innerWidth(this.$refs.text)); // <-- This gets the correct value after a 2 second time out.
    //this.updateFontSize();
}, 2000);

this.$nextTick(this.$nextTick(() => {
    console.log('text elem next:');            
    console.log(el2);
    console.log(this.innerWidth(el2)); // <-- This outputs the same as before the delay
}));
//this.updateFontSize();
```

So as I said, the actual act of sizing the icon works fine. el2 in the above code is the reference to the container for the text. What is happening here is that the width of the text container is taking a considerable amount of time to get an updated correct value from the CSS calculation. The console output looks like this:

```
text elem before:
60
text elem during 1:
74
text elem after:
BEFORE DELAY !!! 
59
text elem next:
59
AFTER DELAY !!!! 
48
```

59 is the value I consistently get directly after modifying the icon size. 48 is the correct value in this case, but I only got that by setting it after an arbitrary timeout. I have gotten the correct value with a timeout as low as 121ms, but at 120 it is outdated again. The issue here that with the correct value, my text label resizes correctly and looks like this:

[image: Correct text placement]

But if I run updateFontSize to soon and get the wrong width returned, I get this:

[image: Incorrect Text Placement]

Using $nexttick doesn't fix it.

I have tried my best to recreate this on codesandbox, but it's kinda wonky. Maybe take a look if you need more context:
[codesandbocklink](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-moser-fuo8l?file=/src/components/GridButton.vue)

I am out of ideas beyond just adding the delay.

Side note: This is not intended to be a responsive design or anything like that. This is for a kiosk type application. The text resizing only happens once on component mounted.

EDIT:: OK, This is a little weird. after playing around some more, tried making a square version of this button. It should look like this:

[image: right]

But instead it came out like this:

[image: wrong]

So I added some console logs like this:
[image: logs]

And this was the output:

[image: results]

Since this is a square icon, the results should be that the width is the same as the font size, like this:

[image: results2]

So I have a new theory... Is it possible that the font size is changing after the pages loads? Or rather, that the width of the icon changed after it was already calculated? Well, as it turns out.. YES!! IT IS! I replaced the icon with standard text that doesn't require any external font to load and:

[image: It Works]

It Worked!

Sooooo...... It depends entirely on how long it takes for the mdi icon pack to load in...

[image]

So I guess the focus of this question is now shifting to...

How do I detect when the mdi icons have finished loading in vuetify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After figuring out that this was a case of fonts not loading quickly, the answer was simple:

```
mounted() {
    this.isMounted = true;
    document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
        console.log('All fonts loaded!');
        this.updateSizes();
    })
    //this.updateSizes();
},
```

This fixed it. I would like the fonts to load faster, but I am glad this works at least.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the ResizeObserver.

Comment: I will keep this in mind for other things, but I just updated the question.. you'll never believe what I narrowed it down to...